# Java: using inheritance if only constructor differs

Tags: java, inheritance

I need to implement the same sequence of commands in a service, but operating on several different database objects, depending on a case. I'm wondering whether it is a good practice to use an inheritance in such case - which would consist in passing a different dao in a specifc class's constructor only. Something like this:

```
 public abstract class Service{

   private Dao dao;

    public Service(Dao dao){
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void mainMethod(){
        dao.step1();
        subMethod();
        dao.step2();
    }

    public void subMethod(){
       //...
    }
}


public class ServiceImpl1 extends Service{

   public ServiceImpl1(DaoImpl1 daoImpl1){
       super(daoImpl1);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to run the *same* operations on multiple *different* types of objects, then those objects must by nature have the same *behavior*. Which means that those classes should all implement the same *interface*, defining your `step1()` and `step2()` methods, so you don't need subclasses, you just need the service to take the interface.

Comment: From the code you post, there's no need to subclass, and one service can handle all `Dao` subclasses if they are passed to the `mainMethod` and not held as an instance member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is useful for delegating messages (method calls) to the superclass with few changes. You're not delegating messages to the parent class though, you're changing the parameter of the constructor. So there is no need to inherit anything.

This is fine:

```
public class Service{ 
    private Dao dao;

    public Service(Dao dao){
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void mainMethod(){
        dao.step1();
        subMethod();
        dao.step2();
    }

    public void subMethod(){
       //...
    }
}
```

You can then make instances like

```
Service posgresService = new Service(new PosgresDao());
Service redisService = new Service(new RedisDao());
```

See [depenency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about inheritance and from the sample code provide, it seems like there will be one ServiceImpl class for each DaoImpl class. It will work, however you could also settle with a single ServiceImpl class for all Dao classes:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    public void mainMethod(Dao dao) {
        dao.step1();
        subMethod();
        dao.step2();
    }

    public void subMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

elsewhere

```
Service service = new ServiceImpl();

// ...

Dao dao1 = new DaoImpl1();
Dao dao2 = new DaoImpl2();

// ...

service.mainMethod(dao1);
service.mainMethod(dao2);
```

Comment: IMO, this looks cleaner. A service should not hold a reference to a DAO.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if -sequence of commands- refers to the exact same commands, I think you should create overloaded methods such as: if not, inheritance would be a good choice in order to keep orden in the code.